# Excel Web Access issue

Tags: excel

I embedded an Excel sheet into SharePoint using the excel web access web part. It works great, the only problem is that it continues to display the Excel sheet on refresh where it was last saved. I set up a macro so that when Excel opens it opens to a default page, but the macro does not seem to be applying on the initial display of the sheet in SharePoint. Does anyone know how to make SharePoint always displays the part of the workbook that I want it to, regardless of where I am at at the time that I save the workbook? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Name the section of excel you want consistently displayed (within excel, go to formulas > name manager).

Reference your named section within the excel web app to consistently show that area.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out just had to put `Worksheets("Dashboard").Activate` on the before save macro.